# How to split results of a multi-dimensional array python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, loops

I have a for loop that multiplies customer data by an array list based on age and state. The loop works but I need to split the results of the output by customer for my next calculation, any Idea how to do this each customers output varies in length based on age.Example customer us111 has an output of size (12,10,10), and customer us112 has an output of size (11,10,10)

```
split=np.random.rand(15, 10, 10)
age = [3,4,9]
customers = np.array([
    [0,1000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,4890,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,624,0,0,0,0,0],
])
results = []
for c, y in zip(customers, age):
    for m in split[y:]:
        c = c @ m
        results.append(c)
results = np.stack(results)
```

For this example split is the array list with size (15,10,10), where age is represented by each matrix example split[0]= age 1 , split[1] =2 and so on until age 15 is reached.Each matrix has 10 states (A-J) for this case.

customer data below:

```
user_id | current_state | age   | amount
us111   |   B           |   3   |  1000
us112   |   D           |   4   |  4890
us113   |   E           |   9   |  624
```

The loop puts each users data in order of their current state
example `us111= np.array([0,1000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])`

and then multiplies by the matrices from the customers age until age 15 is reached.

The current ouptut of the loop appends each customers results below each other but I need to add their user_id next to each array, it can be in a dataframe as well, it doesnt have to be in an array.

Comment: Please consider adding a safe and secure part of the input and the desired output.

Comment: Still a bit unclear what do you want to archive, could you provide a minimum working example till the part you have the problem, and including the desired input and output?

Comment: Ive edited my loop to be a working example, you can run it now. The loop runs but how can I separate the output by user_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can separate it in a dictionary changing the loop:

```
   results_dict = {}
    for _id, c, y in zip(user_id ,customers, age):
        results = []
        for m in split[y:]:
            c = c @ m
            results.append(c)
    results_dict[_id] = results
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo, Do, i just add the user_id's in a 1-d array like I am doing with `age` ?

Comment: when I run this, I only get the results for customer C
`split=np.random.rand(15, 10, 10)`

`age = [3,4,9]`

`customers = np.array([
    [0,1000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,4890,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,624,0,0,0,0,0]])`

`user_id =['a','b','c']`

`results_dict = {}
for _id, c, y in zip(user_id ,customers, age):
    results = []
    for m in split[y:]:
        c = c @ m
        results.append(c)
results_dict[_id] = results`

Comment: For me it works, to see all costumers use: results_dict.keys() to get a specific one results_dict['a'] or results_dict['b'], you are problably checking the results in "results" but your output is now in results_dict, make results = results_dict